# how I can change (1) Yes and (2) No to 0 and 1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a trouble to change (1) Yes and (2) No to 1 and 0?

I tried these but they do not work

```
 h <- lapply(df$LIC, function(x) as.integer(x=="(1) Yes"))
 df$LIC.eq('(1) Yes').mul(1)
 CA <- ifelse(df$LIC=="(1) Yes", 1, 2)
 j<-as.integer(as.character(df$LIC)=="(1) Yes")
 k<-as.numeric(as.factor(df$LIC)=="(1) Yes")
```

Comment: use `as.integer(df$LIC == "(1) Yes")`  Your title says 0 and 1, in the description it is 1 and 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using base r

```
df$LIC[(df$LIC) =="(1) Yes" ]<-"1"

df$LIC[(df$LIC) =="(2) No" ]<-"0"
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` solution without a mutation.

```r
x <- c("yes", "no", "other", "no", "some stuff", "yes")

dplyr::recode(x, yes = 1, no = 0, .default = NA_real_)

#> [1]  1  0 NA  0 NA  1
```

To use it with a dataframe named `df`, you may use:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(LIC = recode(LIC, `(1) Yes` = 1, `(2) No` = 0, .default = NA_real_))
```